# Which prime gaps are known to exist

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It is easily proved that prime gaps can be arbitrarily large by constructing the sequence of composites $(n+1)! + 2, (n+1)! + 3, \dots, (n+1)! + (n+1)$, which are divisible by $2, \dots, n+1$ respectively. It is also easily proved that prime gaps of size $n$ do not exist generally: if $n > 1$ is odd, $p_{i+1} - p_i$ is the difference of two odd numbers and is thus even, so $p_{i+1} - p_i \not = n$.

My question is if it is known, generally, whether for **even** $n \in \mathbb N$, there exists an $i$ such that $p_{i+1} - p_i = n$, and if so how it may be proved.

Comment: Such occurrences would be implied by the [Prime k-tuples conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple) of Hardy and Littlewood, but of course what you ask about is a very simple instance of that.

Comment: Your question is an open problem.